# Why doesn't my database doesn't show up in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently trying to learn backend development using node.js.

I followed the instructions for installing mongoDB, and moved the contents of the bin files into /Users/my-username/mongodb.

Then I did

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

Finally I have these lines of code in the main app.js file,

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vidjot-dev', {
        useMongoClient: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

...

When I run the program I get the mongoDB connected... I also wrote the idea schema, and the process form,

```
// Process Form
app.post('/ideas', (req, res) => {

    const newUser = {
        title: req.body.title,
        details: req.body.details
    }
    new Idea(newUser)
        .save()
        .then(idea => {
            res.redirect('/ideas');
        })

});
```

However when I run mongo in the terminal, only this appears,

```
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

instead of this, that appears in the tutorial I'm using

```
admin       0.000GB
config      0.000GB
local       0.000GB
vidjot-dev  0.000GB
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: try these commands:
> show dbs
> use [dbName]
> show collections

Comment: If `vidjot-dev` is a new database with no collections, it will not show up in the console until you create at least one item in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to hit the endpoint of `/ideas` before the database, collection and documents all get generated dynamically.

Just connecting to mongodb with the js driver won't create anything, unless you explicitly call `createDatabase` ``createCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a title and details in **http://localhost:5000/ideas/add** route.